# What did Victor say to Darcy's character at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, dead-man-down

At the end of [Dead Man Down](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2101341/), Darcy asks Victor if he didn't kill him because he had a family and Victor replies "I didn't kill you because ........". Rewound it 15 times and it is unintelligible to me. Anyone know what he says there?

Comment: If you have the DVD (in order to rewind it), can you activate subtitles?

Comment: Good idea, I Netflix'd it. Going to see if it has subtitles now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Darcy: Did you choose not to kill me 'cause I've got a wife and a kid?
>
> Victor: No. I didn't kill you because they've got you.
>
> (Source: [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2101341/trivia?tab=qt&ref_=tt_trv_qu))

Comment: And what exactly could he have meant with that? (But I haven't seen the movie anyway and unfortunately that wasn't the question at all and you already answered the actual question).

Comment: @ChristianRau i didn't even watched the movie, so didn't even know that. Just searched the quote in IMDb.

Answer (score 1):

He says *"I didn't kill you because they've got you."*

It means he already lost his loved ones in his life therefore he consider's Darcy as a friend whom he cares about. This was foreshadowed in the beginning of the movie, and the night at the cemetery the day Darcy meet with the cemetery owner, and when he asked him to go pick him up at his apartment. Darcy does care about him in his own way, as he tries to venture in certain variables in of his life. He consider's victor a companion by asking him to be there to share the news too alfonze about who the suppose killer will is and by asking victor suggestions and idea' and telling him when important things maybe happening. That's what the "They've got you" impression means in the movie.

Comment: The question is *what did he say?* If you could provide that, I'm sure you'd get upvotes. Otherwise, this doesn't seem like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When Darcy asks Victor at the end of the movie "Did you choose not to kill me cause I've got a wife and a kid?" I thought for sure Victor would say something about Darcy being such a great friend and that he was different from the rest of the crew, so when Victor says "No. I didn't kill you because they've got you", I had to go back and put the subtitles on so I could be sure of what he said and then I went back and watched the very beginning of the movie when Darcy is holding his baby in the car and talking to Victor and in my opinion the reason Victor didn't kill Darcy is because Darcy's wife and baby 'got him', meaning 'they' got his whole heart, that Darcy gets how deep that love goes, and his wife and baby have that from him, 'they' his family 'got him' not the outside world. Just my opinion.

I really liked the movie, Colin Farrell says so much with saying so little, he is an awesome Actor and the rest of the cast was awesome too!

Comment: I got the impression that "They've got you" meant he didn't kill him for his familys sake instead of for Darcys sake. Almost like he didn't want to make it seem like he'd done Darcy a favour, but his family a favour instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is saying, his family has him to come home now. Not because he is close to victor. Or because he had a family.